# read.table function for reading in incomplete data in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have a big table to read into R, and the file is in `.txt` format. In R, I use `read.table` function but there is error in reading it in. The following error message appears:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 28 did not have 23 elements
```

It seems that (counting from the 1st row without counting the header as I specified `skip=`), the data in line 28 have missing elements. I am seeking a way to **automatically** correct this issue by **filtering out** this row. For now, it is impossible for me to even read in the file, so I cannot manipulate in R... Any suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here would be my way to do it: call `read.table` with the option `fill=TRUE`, and exclude the lines without all fields filled afterward (with a call to `count.fields`).

Example:

```
# 1. Data generation, and saving in 'tempfile'
cat("1 John", "2 Paul", "7 Pierre", '9', file = "tempfile", sep = "\n")

# 2. read the data:
data = read.table('tempfile',fill=T)

# 3. exclude incomplete data
c.fields = count.fields('tempfile')
data = data[ - (which(c.fields) != max(c.fields)),]
```

(edited to get automatically the number of rows)

Answer (score 2):

That error also occur when you have a hash symbol (#) in your data.

If that's the case, simply change the option `comment.char` to `comment.char = ""`

```
read.table("file.txt", comment.char = "")
```